# Unable to make the scrollbar disappear - can't figure out how to use right the CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

as you can see [this site](http://glamourina.pl/) has a horizontal scrollbar. The problem happens only in the pages with the comments field - the `<div id="commentsbackground">`.

I want to keep the same style, the same view, however I want the scrollbar to disappear.

```
<div id="commentsbackground">
    <section class="comment">
         <section class="commentsMain"></section>
         <section class="fbcommentbox"></section>
    </section>
</div>
```

The CSS is the following:

```
#commentsbackground {
width: 6000px;
margin-left: -1172px;
background-color: #EAECF3;
overflow: auto;

section.comment {
height: 500px;
margin-left: 1172px;
margin-top: 20px;

.commentsMain {
width: 500px;
padding-left: 20px;
float: left;
border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.13);
padding-right: 20px;
background-color: #E8E8E9;
padding-top: 10px;

.fbcommentbox {
width: 434px;
float: left;
margin-left: 0px;
background-color: #E8E8E9;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-top: 10px;
```

If I remove `margin-left: -1172px;` from `#commentsbackground` and I remove `margin-left: 1172px;` from `section.comment` the scrollbar is still there, but the left side becomes white.
If I also remove the `width: 6000px;` then the two comment boxes break, and the white appears in the right side as well.

If instead I remove only `width: 6000px;`, but I keep the margin-left's, then it breaks and I see white on the right.

I can't find a reasonable solution because the `<div id="commentsbackground">` is inside the `<section class="middle_single">` and the latest has a width of 892px... but I need the background of `<div id="commentsbackground">` to be grey... for every resolution of the screen... the same as you can see it now. But without scrollbar.

I hope somebody can help.

[EDIT] - Today I tried to put the whole comment box in the footer.php file. Just before the `footer-bottom` div. It worked fine, however the site started to have other problems such as: the comments box was showing everywhere, also on the homepage and in the pages and posts with the comments disabled from the wp-admin. So I think that also this was wasn't the right solution for me.

Comment: You should be able to remove scroll bars in Webkit by using the following CSS:

    #element::-webkit-scrollbar { 
        display: none; 
    }

Comment: I have tried it, but it didn't work. However if there is a CSS layout solution to manage those sections to achieve the same visual result, I would prefer it, instead than 'telling' the browsers to not display the scrollbar.

Comment: While removing width:6000px; will break the site, maybe you should then fix it. Having a 6000px div with overflow: auto will cause problems like horizontal scroll bars.

Comment: Try adding this. body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}

Comment: David, you're right. I want to get rid of that 6000px stuff and margins lower than zero. This is why I gave the question here.

Comment: Surjith, thanks. It works, but I am looking for a good css solution, not just a workarount.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of 6000 pixel width and a thousand pixel offset is rediculous. Try changing some of this CSS to remove that crap, seems to work for me.

These will get rid of the scroll bar, but it will make the elemtents sit on top of eachother due to being too wide.

```
.commentsbackground { margin-left: 0; width: 100%; }
.comment { margin-left: 0; }
```

This will reduce the size of the right column, letting the comments and form sit side by side. Please adjust this.

```
.fbcommentbox { width: 335px; }
<span style="height: 200px; width: 335px;"></span>
<iframe width=335>
```

Comment: I cannot edit the `span` because it is added dynamically via the facebook iframe code. And in any case this will make it fit the central column... thus the grey background will appear only in the middle. In the left and right of the `commentsbackground` div, there will be white background. What I need is to have a wide grey background... something similar to the footer. In the footer no matter hat resolution you have, you will always have a black background all wide.